# What to do with the best_score from a grid search obtained from a nested cross validation?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have optimized RandomForest, using GridSearch with a nested cross-validation. 
After that, I know that with the best parameters, I have to train the whole dataset before making predictions on out-of sample data.

Do I have to fit the model twice? One to find the accuracy estimate by nested cross validation and then with the out-of-sample data?

Please check my code:

```
#Load data
for name in ["AWA"]:
for el in ['Fp1']:
    X=sio.loadmat('/home/TrainVal/{}_{}.mat'.format(name, el))['x']
    s_y=sio.loadmat('/home/TrainVal/{}_{}.mat'.format(name, el))['y']
    y=np.ravel(s_y)

    print(name, el, x.shape, y.shape) 
    print("")


#Pipeline
clf = Pipeline([('rcl', RobustScaler()),
                ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])   

#Optimization
#Outer loop
sss_outer = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
#Inner loop
sss_inner = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)


# Use a full grid over all parameters
param_grid = {'clf__n_estimators': [10, 12, 15],
              'clf__max_features': [3, 5, 10],
             }


# Run grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=sss_inner, n_jobs=-1)
#FIRST FIT!!!!!
grid_search.fit(X, y)
scores=cross_val_score(grid_search, X, y, cv=sss_outer)

#Show best parameter in inner loop
print(grid_search.best_params_)

#Show Accuracy average of all the outer loops 
print(scores.mean())

#SECOND FIT!!!
y_score = grid_search.fit(X, y).score(out-of-sample, y)
print(y_score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to understand.

When you do your "first fit", that will fit the gird_search model according to the `sss_inner` cv, and store the result in `grid_search.best_estimator_` (i.e. the best estimator according to the scores on the test data from `sss_inner` folds).

Now you are using that `grid_search` in `cross_val_score` (Nesting). Your fitted model from "first fit" is of no use here. `cross_val_score` will **clone** the estimator, call grid_search.fit() on folds from the `sss_outer` (That means that the training data from `sss_outer` will be presented to grid_search, which will again split it according to `sss_inner`) and present the scores on the test data of `sss_outer`. The model from `cross_val_score` is not fitted.

Now in your "second fit", you are again fitting as you did in "first fit". No need of doing that, because it is already fitted. Just call `grid_search.score()`. It will internally call `score()` from the `best_estimator_`.

You can look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230764/3374996) to learn more about nested cross validation with grid search.

Answer (score 1):

your grid_search.best_estimator_ contains the corss-validated fitted model with best_params_ parameters, no need to refit again.

You can use:

```
clf = grid_search.best_estimator_
preds = clf.predict(X_unseen)
```

Comment: Simply calling `grid_search.score()` or `grid_search.predict()` will have the same effect. Because it will internally access `best_estimator_` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

it is like any normal model that you build. Once you have trained your model ( either through CV or normal train-test split) you use the `.score` or `.predict` using the `best_estimator` from gridsearch to go ahead with the prediction

Sample code I have used recently

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

bootstrap=[True,False]

max_features=[3,4,5,'auto']

n_estimators=[20,75,100]

import time

rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)

param_grid = dict(bootstrap=bootstrap,max_features=max_features,n_estimators=n_estimators)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf_model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = 10, n_jobs=-1)
start_time = time.time()

grid_result=grid.fit(train_iv_data, train_dv_data)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

print("Execution time: " + str((time.time() - start_time)) + ' ms')

classification_report(grid_result.best_estimator_.predict(test_iv_data) , test_dv_data)
```