# TypeError: 'ShuffleSplit' object is not iterable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am using [ShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html) to shuffle data, but I found there is an error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-192f7c286a58> in <module>()
      1 # Fit the training data to the model using grid search
----> 2 reg = fit_model(X_train, y_train)
      3 
      4 # Produce the value for 'max_depth'
      5 print "Parameter 'max_depth' is {} for the optimal model.".format(reg.get_params()['max_depth'])

<ipython-input-34-18b2799e585c> in fit_model(X, y)
     32 
     33     # Fit the grid search object to the data to compute the optimal model
---> 34     grid = grid.fit(X, y)
     35 
     36     # Return the optimal model after fitting the data

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    827 
    828         """
--> 829         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    830 
    831 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    571                                     self.fit_params, return_parameters=True,
    572                                     error_score=self.error_score)
--> 573                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
    574                 for train, test in cv)
    575 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    601 
    602         with self._lock:
--> 603             tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
    604             if len(tasks) == 0:
    605                 # No more tasks available in the iterator: tell caller to stop.

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __init__(self, iterator_slice)
    125 
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
--> 127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)
    129 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in <genexpr>((parameters,))
    572                                     error_score=self.error_score)
    573                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
--> 574                 for train, test in cv)
    575 
    576         # Out is a list of triplet: score, estimator, n_test_samples

TypeError: 'ShuffleSplit' object is not iterable
```

And it showed the warning

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
>     "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py:43: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. This module will be removed in 0.20.
>     DeprecationWarning)

The code will cause the error

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

while the following not

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
```

The current scikit-learn version is 0.18.1.

How does this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While importing GridSearchCV from grid_search like this:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

You must get a warning like the following:

> This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the
>   model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and
>   functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV
>   iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be
>   removed in 0.20.

This is self explanatory and conforms to what you are experiencing.

**Solution**:-
**Dont use the deprecated `grid_search` package**. Use the new `model_selection`.