# Nested cross-validation example on Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nested, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm trying to work my head around the example of [Nested vs. Non-Nested CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html) in Sklearn. I checked multiple answers but I am still confused on the example.
To my knowledge, a nested CV aims to use a different subset of data to select the best parameters of a classifier (e.g. C in SVM) and validate its performance. Therefore, from a dataset X, the **outer** 10-folds CV (for simplicity n=10) creates 10 training sets and 10 test sets:

```
(Tr0, Te0),..., (Tr0, Te9)
```

Then, the **inner** 10-CV splits **EACH** outer training set into 10 training and 10 test sets:

```
From Tr0: (Tr0_0,Te_0_0), ... , (Tr0_9,Te0_9)
From Tr9: (Tr9_0,Te_9_0), ... , (Tr9_9,Te9_9)
```

Now, using the inner CV, we can find the best values of *C* for every single outer Training set. This is done by testing all the possible values of *C* with the inner CV. The value providing the highest performance (e.g. accuracy) is chosen for that specific outer Training set. Finally, having discovered the best *C* values for every outer Training set, we can calculate an unbiased accuracy using the outer Test sets. With this procedure, the samples used to identify the best parameter (i.e. *C*) are not used to compute the performance of the classifier, hence we have a totally unbiased validation.

The example provided in the [Sklearn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html) is:

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

# Non_nested parameter search and scoring
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

# Nested CV with parameter optimization
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

From what I understand, the code simply calculates the scores using two different cross-validations (i.e. different splits into training and test set). Both of them used the entire dataset. The *GridCV* identifies the best parameters using one (of the two CVs), then *cross_val_score* calculates, with the second CV, the performance when using the best parameters.

Am I interpreting a *Nested CV* in the wrong way? What am I missing from the example?

Comment: You can take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230764/3374996) to get a step by step analysis.

Comment: I got really confused by the names and the order, as I expected outer_cv to be used "before" inner_cv. So, the nesting occurs because we pass clf, that is an instance of GridSearchCV to cross_val_scor? Hence, in simple words, cross_val_score, first split X into X_tr, X_te, then X_tr is passed to clf that, because is an instance of GridSearchCV, will further split X_tr, into X_tr_tr and X_tr_te?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. One `X_tr` is splitted into `X_tr_tr` and `X_tr_te` for number of folds defined in `inner_cv`. Then according to the `outer_cv` some other part of the data becomes `X_tr` which is then again sent to `inner_cv`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, thanks Vivek. So, if we directly pass clf = SVM() to cross_val_score we obtain a "traditional" cross-fold validation.

Comment: Yes, the whole nested cross-validation takes place because of cross-validation done in the GridSearchCV. If using simple estimators, this becomes the simple cross-validation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scikit-learn GridSearchCV with multiple repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228735/scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-with-multiple-repetitions)

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding of nested cross-validation (CV) is correct, but it seems there might be a misunderstanding in how the example code is structured.

In the example provided by scikit-learn, nested cross-validation is indeed being utilized. Let's break down the code to understand how it fits into the concept of nested CV:

Initialization of CV Splits:

```
inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
```

Two sets of cross-validation iterators are initialized:
inner_cv and outer_cv. Both use 4-fold cross-validation, but they serve different purposes.

Non-Nested Parameter Search and Scoring:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_
```

In this part, GridSearchCV is used with the inner cross-validation (inner_cv). It searches over the parameter grid p_grid for the best hyperparameters using cross-validation. The best model found is then trained on the entire dataset (X_iris, y_iris) and its performance score (e.g., accuracy) is recorded.

Nested CV with Parameter Optimization:

```
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

Here, cross_val_score is used with the outer cross-validation (outer_cv). The clf model (which was trained using the best parameters found during the inner CV) is evaluated using cross-validation. This process is repeated for each fold in the outer CV. Finally, the mean of the scores obtained across the folds is calculated and recorded.

So, in summary, the nested cross-validation in this example involves:

Inner CV: Used for hyperparameter tuning (GridSearchCV) to find the best model.
Outer CV: Used to evaluate the performance of the best model found by the inner CV.
This structure ensures that the evaluation of the model's performance is unbiased, as the hyperparameters are optimized on a separate set of data within each fold of the outer CV.

Your interpretation seems to be correct, but the example does indeed showcase the use of nested cross-validation. Each fold in the outer CV is used to assess the generalization performance of the model trained on the corresponding training data, and the hyperparameters are selected using the inner CV to avoid data leakage and overfitting.